# Remove a specific string from an array and change the rest to a numeric value

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array:

```
var myArray = ["234&234", "123&321", "456&432"],
```

How do I remove the "&" from each array element, and change the left string "234234" to a numeric value of 234234?

Answer (score 1):

`myArray.forEach(function(part, index, theArray){
  myArray[index] = parseInt(part.replace("&", ""))
})`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run on the array by using for loop,
and and replace the '&' by using replace function.

```
var myArray = ["234&234", "123&321", "456&432"];
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
 myArray[i] = myArray[i].replace('&','');
}
console.log(myArray);
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you @itzikb!

Answer (score 0):

You could use map() method of your array :

```
var input = ["234&234", "123&321", "456&432"];

var output = input.map(x => Number.parseInt(x.replace("&", "")));

console.log(output); // [ 234234, 123321, 456432 ]
```